# Changing the color of two panels

Tags: asp.net

In [this ASP.NET page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2ulT.png):

[image: My ASP.NET page]

I need to make Panel 1 Red and Panel 2 blue. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: You do not know how to use basic CSS? Give it a class

Comment: CssClass、ID 。I have tried, invalid

I have a picture message in 2F

Answer (score 0):

test.aspx

have two panel

but i need panel1 → GroupingText (Color is Red)

but i need **panel2** → GroupingText (Color is **Blue**)

Why does not this no independent property
Not really understand @@?

Use CssClass → X
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoFnD.png

Use ID → X
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkiT4.png

T.T

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CssClass = "something" into your panel atributes and create ccs Class for panel one and for panel 2 with color: red; and color: blue;

Comment: CssClass、ID 。I have tried, invalid I have a picture message in 2F ><"